# Coloring Mesh Objects in Directx 9

Tags: c++, colors, directx, vertex

Hello guys so I have this portion of my code dedicated to coloring the teapot. I know something is wrong with this code, I'm just guessing to be honest what to do. So can you guys fix this stuff for me thanks.

if you dont understand the code, I really dont have time to post the decleration variables, how do you change the color of the default geometric objects such as teapot, box, sphere, etc etc.

```
// Teapot section
D3DXCreateTeapot(device, &Teapot, 0);
Teapot->GetVertexBuffer(&Teapot_VB);

ColorVertex* t_v;

device->CreateVertexBuffer(
    Teapot->GetNumVertices()*sizeof(ColorVertex),
    D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY,
    ColorVertex::FVF,
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    &Teapot_VB,
    NULL);

Teapot_VB->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&t_v, 0);
for(int i = 0; i <= Teapot->GetNumVertices(); i++)
{
    t_v[i].m_color = RED;
}
Teapot_VB->Unlock();
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you only need to change the RED to some other color. It looks like you're creating one VB per object so everything should work ok.

Comment: the teapot is displaying as white under device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, false); I made a cube out of manually putting vertex info and color info and it work. This teapot from the default geometry wont work for some reason. I tried changing the color(colors are predefined from my header) but still wont work. Can you lay out a blue print to how you actually do it?

Comment: Why do you get the teapot's vertex buffer and afterwards create a fresh VB at the same address? If the teapot's VB is not writeable, you should make a new one copying the teapots position information.

Comment: Never mind I got what you said, Thanks alot.